# Sample classification datasets?

Tags: remote-sensing, classification, digital-image-processing, data

I was looking for some **publicly** available ground data classification datasets, specifically, locations in e.g. latitude/longitude with a description of the land cover/land use, and a reference e.g. Landsat image. The aim of this is to have a sample classification dataset with which to try out different classification algorithms.

And yes, I could do this by hand, selecting random pixels from a landcover dataset, but I'd like to at least have some sort of ground truth to compare with and I'd rather use some freely available data that people have used for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Europe, there are:

- [CORINE land cover](http://ec.europa.eu/maritimeaffairs/atlas/maritime_atlas/#lang=EN;bkgd=5:1;mode=1;pos=5.382:51.427:7;theme=75:0.9:1;) (downloadable from [there](http://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/clc-2006-vector-data-version-2))
- [LUCAS](http://epp.eurostat.ec.europa.eu/portal/page/portal/lucas/introduction) (see it [there](http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistical-atlas/gis/viewer/?myConfig=LUCAS-2012.xml)).

Comment: LUCAS looks like the stuff I want, but I think that the individual data points are not available for download, only data aggregated by NUTS?